# Excel.IExcelDataReader skips reading cells randomly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I am trying to read an excel file into a table using Excel.IExcelDataReader

Code to read:

```
Dim reader As Excel.IExcelDataReader = Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(filename)
```

When I visualize the table dataset, I notice some cells are randomly skipped by the reader in a couple of columns. I tried creating new excel file and copy - pasted (special > values) data but the result is same.

Excel File:

[image]

Dataset:

[image]

See that data after 'Videocon V1528' is not captured in Dataset. Just to add, a couple more columns are being skipped after certain row (not the same row in all columns).

I know it's weird but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Was the Excel data an import or scrape? Are there linefeeds, zero-length spaces, etc in the cell data? Does a `LEN(...)` report the correct number of visible characters in the cell data?

Comment: The excel file is simple xls file (Microsoft Office 97/2000) format. When I checked LEN(...) on the first cell being skipped, I found invalid characters in the cell. Removing them resolved the issue. Thanks a lot @Jeeped